# Interference of a current carrying conductor on other cable

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I need to solve a problem. Below figure explains the setup.

[image: Setup Image]

> We have a current carrying conductor (Wire A) which is carrying 3A of current, which is generated by a 400 kHz sine wave source
>
> We have another conductor (Wire B) which is placed 5 cm from the Wire A.

I wanted to know what is the induced current in Wire B, because of current in Wire A.

I thought, I should approach problem in 2 steps.

First, Identify the magnetic field field produced by Wire A near to Wire B. I initially thought, I should use Maxwell's equation for the same.

$$B =\frac{μ_0 \times I}{2 \times \pi \times d}$$
However, that equation is applicable for DC current not for time varying sine wave current.

Secondly, after identifying the magnetic field, use Faraday's law to identify the EMF generated in Wire B.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Since the ends of wire B are not connected to anything, there is an open circuit, and no current flows in wire B.

Comment: Photon is on to something here. If the wire B is just a finite piece of wire not connected to anything as depicted, then the current will be very small and hard to determine, due to electrostatic field cancelling most of the effect of the induced field due to A.

Comment: The question would have a solution if the wire B was a closed circuit of known dimensions and resistance.

Comment: I agree with you all. Let us assume that there is 10k Ohm connected in between the ends of Wire B.

Comment: Dimensions of circuits need to be defined. If the wire with the resistor in the second circuit is right next to the wire B, then total induced EMF will be close to zero.